# javascript getelementbyID in col-md-4

Tags: javascript

I want my GetelementbyID to post a col-md-4 for each img that is in the folder images/gallerij
How can ik get the getelementbyid to post for each img in the folder a col-md-4.
That he will give 3 img for each row?

```
<div id="product" class="product">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="imggal" class="col-md-4">
            </div>

        <!---->
        <script> 
    function mijFunctie(){
     var i = 1;

     while(i<25) {

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = "images/gallerij/" + i + ".jpeg";
        document.getElementById('imggal').appendChild(img);
        i++;
     }

    }
```

should i try something like

document.getElementById(="col-md-4">'imggal').appendChi‌​ld(img);

Comment: *"but now he is only posting it in 1 col-md-4 and not next to eachoter"* Well, yes; you're selecting the exact same element each time.

Comment: What does the markup of the *next* `div` you want to put the image in look like? If it also has `id="imggal"`, the HTML is invalid; the same `id` value cannot be used on more than one element. While it's possible on modern browsers to code around that, by far the better solution is to use unique `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

Edited : Iam not try your codes but this is my codes to do that :

```
var max = 25, images = '<img/>';
for(var i = 1; i < max; i++){
  $('#imggal').append($(images).attr({id:i,src:'your src'}));
}
```

Comment: yes this should work. but this is not valid for me i think (i have tried this and its not). i thought maybe i should do something like  
        document.getElementById(<div>="col-md-4">'imggal').appendChild(img);

Comment: oh you want to apend divs not img ?? Try with it : var max = 25, divs = '<div class="col-md-4"></div>';
for(var i = 1; i < max; i++){
  $('.col-md-12').append($(divs).html($('<img/>').attr({id:i,src:'your src'}))); .But you must remove div with class col-md-4 first. I am not try this codes so you can give a notif for me if not work.
}

Comment: But now it would not take the images from my src and place it into each div="col-md-4".

Im sorry maybe i am asking my question wrong, what i try to do is create a function to get automatic images from my src. The img that i get automatic from the src i want to put in a div that is a col-md-4. And i want this to repeat for each image in the folder

Comment: Because i dont understand what you want :D

Comment: did you read my last post? i tried to asking it as good as possible

Comment: Are you want to loop divs with class md-4 ? then that divs have 3 images ? Sure i dont understand with your word statement 'getElementById' in question, because you want to loop divs with class md-4

Comment: i am sorry, i want to loop divs with in each div a images that is get from a folder. really sorry for this poor way os asking something